How to download single file from SFTP (WINSCP) server while using Azure Function?
Currently, there are methods
session.GetFiles(...),


session.GetFilesToDirectory(...)

But both of these methods have required parameter for localDirectory. Since I'm using Azure functions, there is no local directory at all. There isn't also an option to save those download information into MemoryStream as far as I've checked.
Is there anyway I can download the file? Even if there is any option to just generate download URL would be helpful.
